# How to increase the intelligence of interaction between a chatbot with an llm model through the processing of information from pdf documents?

Tags: javascript, python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am working on a chatbot connected to the OpenAI API that is responsible for answering questions related to documents that have previously been processed and finally saved in a vector database.

The process that the PDF documents have followed consists of dividing the entire document into chunks and finally vectorizing them and saving them to a vector database that also connects to the interface where the user asks about the information of said document. I am also using python for the web interface and langchain as the framework to connect to the OpenAI APIs.

However, when a user asks a question on the interface they sometimes get confused and give a very similar answer. This is because the PDF document has subtopics and among them some concepts are similar. So the question the user asks must be very specific. But what happens if the user doesn't know the topic and starts asking general questions? you will get wrong answers (Although for the model they will be fine)

So now I want to improve the quality of my chatbot's responses. I want him to be smarter. I am thinking that the PDF document should be pre-treated, organized or divided into each subtopic. So that it is saved in an orderly manner in the vector database. Or maybe another tool is what I should modify? like python code.

Some of you have had the same problem of poor quality answers due to many overlaps in various sections of the PDF document, and would like better quality and specific answers. Maybe you can comment and share a solution to this problem.

I appreciate it very much.

Comment: what is your main question here?

Comment: Hello @Yilmaz, the main question is to apply correct treatment to PDF documents. Thanks.